# React native navigating directly to a given URL goes to home everytime

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

So I have an React Native Expo app, using `BottomTabNavigator`. I'm using React Navigation authentication flow, so if I have a token, I go directly to the `BottomTabNavigator`, otherwise I go to the `AuthenticationStack` (login page)

```
<RootStack.Navigator headerMode="none">
  {isLoading ? (
    <RootStack.Screen name="loading" component={LoadingScreen} />
  ) : userToken ? (
    <RootStack.Screen
      name="root"
      component={BottomTabNavigator}
      options={{ ...TransitionPresets.ModalSlideFromBottomIOS }}
    />
  ) : (
    <RootStack.Screen
      name="auth"
      component={AuthenticationStackScreen}
      options={{ ...TransitionPresets.ModalSlideFromBottomIOS }}
    />
  )}
</RootStack.Navigator>
```

My BottomTabNavigator has 3 tabs: `Home, Notifications & Settings`. I'm using expo-linking and config is:

```
  prefixes: [Linking.makeUrl("/")],
  config: {
    screens: {
      root: {
        screens: {
          home: "home",
          notifications: "notifications",
          settings: "settings"
        }
      },
      auth: {
        screens: {
          login: "login",
          register: "register"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

If I launch the project on web, everytime I refresh being on any route different than `Home` (on `Settings` for example), will navigate to `Home`. I guess I have a state persistance problem, but I don't really know how to manage this. How can I "tell" the navigator to stay on the current route without navigating automatically to `Home`?

It also happens if I copy paste the url link into a new web browser tab. If my route is: `myApp/settings`, it will navigate to `myApp/home`.

---

**EDIT**:

If I remove the `isLoading` & `userToken` check, and leave it just with the `rootStack`, it works fine. So the problem I guess it's coming from that

Comment: You shouldn't put your splash screen in the stack navigator. Render it before rendering the navigation container.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks!